# Direct Phone Charge from Solar Cells via USB

Tags: usb, cellphone, solar-energy

I have a 19V 0.7A series of solar cells I'd like to connect to a standard 5V USB breakout PCB for phone charging. Do I need to worry about causing damage to the phone or battery without a regulator?

In other words, is the charging regulator in a typical phone capable of regulating 19V 0.7A?

Comment: Yes you need to worry about this. This will not be a healthy solution.

Comment: I sense magic smoke...

Comment: 19V will usually be fatal. A preregulator is needed - either switching or linear OR clamp the panel to about  5 to 5.5V - it will act as a constant current source with I ~= k x light level. 
This provides the same power as a linear regulator but dissipates far less energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical phones are very "economical devices". If their charge environment is revolving around standard USB (which is 5 V by default), no-one will design the internal charger that is tolerant to 19V. Most typical line of charging ICs from Texas Instruments has maximum input level of 6-7 V, (say, [BQ24xxx line](http://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ic/products.html#p1152=1;1&p1153max=0.25;4&p2656max=5.5;12)), and the circuit will shut down if this level is exceeded.

Only most recent, Power-Delivery capable phones might have circuits that are 20-25 V tolerant, but again, you have to engage into some complex protocol to allow this input to be functional.

So in short, you need to provide a step-down converter to 5V if you want to charge a "typical phone" from raw solar panel.